# Comma sign in Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, punctuation

I am using

```
\documentclass[a4paper 12pt]{article}
```

and

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

to write a report. The problem i am facing is that latex is not putting comma between the author names in my bibliography. can anyone please help me to sort this problem out?

Comment: Can you make a small document that shows the effect?

Comment: Comma will be put only if there are more than two authors. How many authors do you have? If there are only two authors, bibtex will put `and` in the middle when you use `unsrt`.

Comment: No MWE after two weeks => 'too localized' as this is not the standard behaviour.

Comment: This is probably due to a wrong way to input authors names in the `.bib` file.

Answer (score 1):

Without a minimal working example your problem is too localized. The following examples shows commas between authors.

```
\documentclass[a4paper 12pt]{article} 

\begin{document}
\cite{whole-collection}

\cite{unpublished-full}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} 
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

[image]